# CSS Grid template-rows value doesn't change

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I got a problem with CSS Grid (I just started learning it). When I type the values of  my `grid-template-rows:` in em, it works perfectly. But if I use percentage, all rows are all same height. I used to give them: 10% 80% 10% for: `header, main, footer,` but for some reason they are all same big. It makes no different if I change the Wrapper height(grid container element) from % to em or whatsoever. Here's my code:

```css
  
    #Wrapper {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
     grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%;
     min-height: 20em;
     grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "main main main"
      "footer footer footer"
      
    }
    
    header {
     background-color: #593093;
     grid-area: header;
    
    }
    
    main {
     background-color: #2AABBB;
     grid-area: main;
    
    }
    
    footer {
     background-color: #2F6692;
     grid-area: footer;
    
    }
    
    
    h3 {
     margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
     <div id="Wrapper">
      <header>
       <h3>Header</h3>
    
      </header>
      <main>
       <h3>Main</h3>
      </main>
      <footer>
       <h3>Footer</h3>
    
      </footer>
     </div>
```

Comment: You will probably need to set height to `100%` to body and html elements as well as `#Wrapper` div.

Comment: That didn't changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `#Wrapper` doesn't have a specified height or parent height. You can't use `%` as unit when the parent's height is not specified. Height in `em` is working since `em` is a absolute unit relative to parent `px`.

Define the height of the `#Wrapper` will be good to go.

```
#Wrapper{
  height: 500px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrMwQM